# BEGIN,CHECK,INIT& END blocks in Perl

Tags: perl

As I understand these special functions inside Perl code, BEGIN and CHECK blocks run during the compilation phase while INIT and END blocks run during actual execution phase.

I can understand using these blocks inside actual Perl code (Perl libraries) but what about using them inside modules? Is that possible?

Since when we use `use <Module-name>` the module is compiled, so in effect BEGIN and CHECK blocks run. But how will the INIT and END blocks run since module code I don't think is run in the true sense. We only use certain functions from inside the modules.

Comment: This is described in detail in Chapter 16, "Compiling", of [Programming Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short**   The special code blocks in packages loaded via `use` are processed and run (or scheduled to run) as encoutered, in the same way and order as in `main::`, since `use` itself is a `BEGIN` block.

---

Excellent documentation on this can be found [in perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END). From this section

> A BEGIN code block is executed as soon as possible, that is, the moment it is completely defined, even before the rest of the containing file (or string) is parsed.

Since the `use` statements *are* `BEGIN` blocks they run as soon as encountered.  From [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

> It is exactly equivalent to
>
> ```
> BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
> ```

So the `BEGIN` blocks in a package run in-line with others, as they are encountered. The `END` blocks in a package are then also compiled in the same order, as well as the other special blocks.  As for the order of (eventual) execution

> An `END` code block is executed as late as possible ...

and

> You may have multiple END blocks within a file--they will execute in reverse order of definition; that is: last in, first out (LIFO)

The order of compilation and execution of `INIT` and `CHECK` blocks follows suit.

---

Here is some code to demonstrate these special code blocks used in a package.

File **PackageBlocks.pm**

```
package PackageBlocks;
use warnings;

BEGIN { print "BEGIN block in the package\n" }
INIT  { print "INIT  block in the package\n" }
END   { print "END   block in the package\n" }
1;
```

The main script

```
use warnings;

BEGIN { print "BEGIN in main script.\n" }

print "Running in the main.\n";

INIT { print "INIT in main script.\n" }

use PackageBlocks;

END   { print "END in main script.\n" }
BEGIN { print "BEGIN in main script, after package is loaded.\n" }

print "After use PackageBlocks.\n";
```

Output

```
BEGIN in main script.
BEGIN block in the package
BEGIN in main script, after package is loaded.
INIT in main script.
INIT block in the package
Running in the main.
After use PackageBlocks.
END in main script.
END block in the package
```

The `BEGIN` block in the package runs in order of appearance, in comparison with the ones in `main::`, and before `INIT`. The `END` block runs at end, 
and the one in the package runs after the one in `main::`, since the `use` comes before it in this example.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question, which is about `INIT` and `END` blocks within a Perl module

Comment: @Borodin Oh ... the last paragraph tripped me up, thank you.  I'll add that.

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy to test for yourself

`use Module` (and `require EXPR` and `do EXPR` and `eval EXPR`) compile the Perl code and then immediately run it

That is where the `1;` at the end of most modules is picked up. If executing the module's code after compiling it doesn't return a *true* value then `require` will fail

Admittedly there usually isn't much use for an `INIT` or an `END` block, because the run-time phase is so intimately tied to the compilation, and because modules are generally about defining subroutines, but the option is there if you want it