# Perl How to remove a directory after program finishes

Tags: perl

I want to allow users to pass a cleanup argument through the command line (such as --clean) to remove a directory containing no longer needed files. When I try to do a remove_tree, it does during the program run. How can I get it so it does it once the entire run is complete and then removes the directory that I no longer need?

So I have `/$cleanup` in my getOptions.

```
if (defined $cleanup){
remove_tree("my path here");
}
```

It is not a question of HOW to remove directories, but how to remove them only upon user option through command line.

EDIT:
I tried with the END block.

Here is how my code looks.

```
@arr = (John, Daniel, Mary); #there is path for each one of them generated
foreach my $arr (@array){
......
END{
remove_tree("/mydir/names/$array/outputfiles") if defined $cleanup;
};
}
```

I do this because I want it done for each name but it doesn't work. If I do it like this, it does work but I'd rather have one line instead of three.

```
@arr = (John, Daniel, Mary); #there is path for each one of them generated
foreach my $arr (@array){
......
END{
remove_tree("/mydir/names/John/outputfiles") if defined $cleanup;
};
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197641/discussion-between-noah-and-sfr).

Comment: The `END` blocks shouldn't be inside other expressions (or any of the other special block should, for that matter);  they're listed nicely at the beginning or end of a program.  _Inside_ you can do what you need, so `END { if (defined $cleanup) { for my $name (@arr) { remove_tree( "/dir/../$name/..") } } }`.  Or `remove_tree(/../$_/../) for @arr`, but I wouldn't worry about saving a line of code in an `END` block

Comment: @zdim It worked! Thanks so much. This is my first time using an END block so it all makes sense now.

Comment: Great :)  They _can_ be overused (or abused), but are very useful when used in good taste.  I'll find examples of other substantial use and post links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That kind of work is one of the main uses of [END blocks](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END)

```
use File::Path;
...

END {
    remove_tree( ... ) if defined $cleanup;
};
```

This special code block

> is executed as late as possible, that is, after perl has finished running the program and just before the interpreter is being exited, even if it is exiting as a result of a `die()` function.  (But not if it's morphing into another program via `exec`, or being blown out of the water by a signal--you have to trap that yourself (if you can).)

The `END` blocks also run on `exit`, and a parent's `END` block runs in a child process *as well*. They can be suppressed by using [POSIX](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#FUNCTIONS)::`_exit(status)` instead of `exit`.

Note that this is a special phase in the program lifetime and some things may not work the same. For example, signal handlers are gone as `RUN` phase ended (can be reinstalled in the first `END` block). However, you can work with the filesystem and clean up files etc.

Comment: i tried to insert the end block in my "if defined" statement but it didn't work.

Comment: other way around. END blocks just make whatever is inside run at the end

Comment: @sfr  One thing I can readily find -- see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37724112/4653379) for more discussion and some examples.  (Correction for the above comment: the "_phase_" associated with the term "runtime" is called `RUN`.)

Comment: @sfr Ah, I see what you mean -- you do `END { remove_tree(...) if $cleanup }`

Comment: @sfr Edited with comments

Comment: So this does work if I do specify the path exactly. I have elements of an array that fills in part of my path. So I get the warning that uninitialized value $arr in concatenation or string at line..... and it doesn't do the remove. I will update my post to show the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

If the directory to be used is temporary (created by the code, and then cleaned up at the end), just use [File::Temp](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) with the "cleanup" option.

```
use File::Temp;
$dir = tempdir( CLEANUP => 1 );
```